# Read contacts using bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet, obex

I'm trying to read contacts from my mobile device using **32feet** library and i'm having a bad request error when I try. The device is paired with my app. This is my code:

```
var item = (BluetoothDeviceInfo)listBox.SelectedItem;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    item.Update();
    item.Refresh();

    item.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.PhonebookAccess, true);

    if (OBEXOpenStream(item.DeviceAddress.ToString()))
    {
        if (OBEXConnect())
        {
            string tName = "";
            string tType = "text/x-vCard";
            string tFileContent = "";
            int result = OBEXRequest("GET", tName, tType, tFileContent);

            item.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    OBEXCloseStream();

});
```

I dont know if there are another ways to get the contacts using OBEX.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made a mistake when you have to send a empty name header for the request. The variable `tName` should be `null` not `""`, as `""` is `0x00` in bytes, not empty name header. The library will send the size of the name header as`0x0004`, not `0x0003`, which is required for your vCard request. This is a common mistake, and I commited it too :)

**OR**
Why do you give `tFileContents` parameter? It is not necessary as I know. You may have to delete the parameter. According to IRDA spec, it is not needed.

Sorry for poor English and I hope this answer helped a lot.