# Read contacts using obex in c#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet, obex

I'm trying to read contacts using 32feet library for c#. I'm connecting my PC to mobile device via bluetooth, and when I try to execute this code always give me bad request error

```
LocalInfo.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.PhonebookAccessPce, true);
BluetoothAddress addr = BluetoothAddress.Parse("00:00:00:00:00:00");
BluetoothEndPoint rep = new BluetoothEndPoint(addr, BluetoothService.PhonebookAccessPse);
BluetoothClient cli = new BluetoothClient();
cli.Connect(rep);

Uri uri = new Uri(ObexUri.UriSchemeObex + "://" + addr + "/telecom/pb.vcf");
ObexWebRequest request = new ObexWebRequest(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/x-vCard";
ObexWebResponse resp = (ObexWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And in the constructor:

```
private BluetoothDeviceInfo localinfo = null;
public BluetoothDeviceInfo LocalInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return localinfo = (localinfo ?? new BluetoothDeviceInfo(BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.LocalAddress));
        }
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is the URI wrong, or I need a different Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not an expert in 32feet, I know that the `Name Header` of the `GET` request retrieving vcard should be `null`. Why don't you try using empty or `null` URI?

**Edit** I found some statements that requires you to use obex-ftp instead of obex.

> Remarks
>
> For Object Exchange the method code is mapped to the equivalent HTTP
>   style method. For example "PUT", "GET" etc. "PUT" is the default
>   value. There is new support for GET as of version 2.5.
>
> To use GET change the Method to " GET " and you must also use scheme
>   " obex-ftp " in the URL instead of the usual " obex " -- unless you
>   know that the default OBEX server you are connecting supports GET.

And it is cited from [here](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/32feet.NET/InTheHand.Net.Personal/ObexWebRequest/P/Method).

**Edit**

> Phonebook Access Similar to file transfer, but uses a target {0x79,
>   0x61, 0x35, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xC5, 0x11, 0xD8, 0x09, 0x66, 0x08, 0x00,
>   0x20, 0x0C, 0x9A, 0x66}; phonebook entries can be listed (with various
>   possible orderings and filters) and retrieved from certain directories
>   under telecom/ using GET and SETPATH

--according to wikipedia you should put some specific UUID to `TARGET` header when you connect to `phonebook access`.

Like codes from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/bluetooth/+/lollipop-dev/src/android/bluetooth/client/pbap/BluetoothPbapObexSession.java#L203), you should not only specify PBAP Service UUID `0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` on RFCOMM level, but also have to specify  target header UUID `0x79, 0x61, 0x35, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0xc5, 0x11, (byte) 0xd8, 0x09, 0x66, 0x08, 0x00, 0x20, 0x0c, (byte) 0x9a, 0x66` on OBEX level in type header.

Comment: Hi, thanks to answer. Using empty or null URI give me same error: System.Net.WebException: 'GET failed with code: BadRequest, Final'

Comment: Do you have any example that can work? I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Try this.
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872112/read-contacts-using-bluetooth
   With patching "" to null. I'll have to learn more about 32feet to post better answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Using both gives me socket exception. I don't know if the uri I'm using ("telecom/pb.vcf") is correct...

Comment: According to wikipedia ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange) it is correct uri.

Comment: How about not specifing contenttype? And what socket error do you get?

Comment: Hi, thanks to answer. ObexUri doesn't have ObexUri.UriSchemeObexPbap, only Obex, ObexFtp and ObexSync

Comment: I found nice answer for you! Try specifying TARGET header of your connect request.