# Read mobile phone book using obex in c#

Tags: c#, obex, phonebook

i have a OBEXConnect and OBEXRequest custom functions, i am not using library for it
OBEXConnect function is as following

```
    private bool OBEXConnect()
    {
        //send client request
        byte[] ConnectPacket = new byte[7];

        ConnectPacket[0] = 0x80;            // Connect
        ConnectPacket[1] = 0x00;            // Packetlength Hi Byte
        ConnectPacket[2] = 0x07;            // Packetlength Lo Byte
        ConnectPacket[3] = 0x10;            // Obex v1
        ConnectPacket[4] = 0x00;            // no flags
        ConnectPacket[5] = 0x20;            // 8k max packet size Hi Byte
        ConnectPacket[6] = 0x00;            // 8k max packet size Lo Byte

        stream.Write(ConnectPacket,0,ConnectPacket.Length);

        //listen for server response
        byte[] ReceiveBufferA = new byte[3];
        stream.Read(ReceiveBufferA,0,3);

        if (ReceiveBufferA[0] == 160) // 0xa0
        { 

            //success, decode rest of packet
            int plength = (0xff * ReceiveBufferA[1]) + ReceiveBufferA[2]; //length of packet is...

            //listen for rest of packet
            byte[] ReceiveBufferB = new byte[plength-3];
            stream.Read(ReceiveBufferB,0,plength-3);

            int obver = ReceiveBufferB[0]; //server obex version (16 = v1.0)
            int cflags = ReceiveBufferB[1]; //connect flags
            int maxpack = (0xff * ReceiveBufferB[2]) + ReceiveBufferB[3]; //max packet size

            return true;
        } 
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and here is OBEXRequest function

```
private int OBEXRequest(string tReqType, string tName, string tType, string tFileContent)
    {
        //send client request

        int i;
        int offset;
        int packetsize;
        byte reqtype = 0x82;

        int tTypeLen = 0x03;
        int typeheadsize;
        int typesizeHi = 0x00;
        int typesizeLo = 0x03;

        //tName = "contact.vcf";
        //tType = "text/x-vCard";
        //tFileContent = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nN:;aardvark\r\nFN:aardvark\r\nEND:VCARD\r\n";

        if (tReqType == "GET")
        {
            reqtype = 0x83;         // 131 GET-Final
        }

        if (tReqType == "PUT")
        {
            reqtype = 0x82;         // 130 PUT-Final
        }

        packetsize = 3;

        //Name Header
        int tNameLength = tName.Length;
        int nameheadsize = (3 + (tNameLength*2) + 2); 
        int namesizeHi = (nameheadsize & 0xff00)/0xff;
        int namesizeLo = nameheadsize & 0x00ff;
        packetsize = packetsize + nameheadsize;

        if (tType != "") 
        {
            //Type Header
            tTypeLen = tType.Length;
            typeheadsize = 3 + tTypeLen + 1;
            typesizeHi = (typeheadsize & 0xff00)/0xff;
            typesizeLo = typeheadsize & 0x00ff;
            packetsize = packetsize + typeheadsize;
        }

        //Body
        int fileLen = tFileContent.Length;
        int fileheadsize = 3 + fileLen ;
        int filesizeHi = (fileheadsize & 0xff00)/0xff;;
        int filesizeLo = fileheadsize & 0x00ff;;

        packetsize = packetsize + fileheadsize;

        int packetsizeHi = (packetsize & 0xff00)/0xff;
        int packetsizeLo = packetsize & 0x00ff;

        byte[] tSendByte = new byte[packetsize];

        //PUT-final Header
        tSendByte[0] = reqtype;                                     // Request type e.g. PUT-final 130
        tSendByte[1] = Convert.ToByte(packetsizeHi);                // Packetlength Hi
        tSendByte[2] = Convert.ToByte(packetsizeLo);                // Packetlength Lo

        offset = 2;

        //Name Header
        tSendByte[offset+1] = 0x01;                                 // HI for Name header       
        tSendByte[offset+2] = Convert.ToByte(namesizeHi);           // Length of Name header (2 bytes per char)
        tSendByte[offset+3] = Convert.ToByte(namesizeLo);           // Length of Name header (2 bytes per char)

        // Name+\n\n in unicode
        byte[] tNameU = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(tName);
        tNameU.CopyTo(tSendByte,offset+4);

        offset = offset + 3 + (tNameLength*2);
        tSendByte[offset+1] = 0x00;                                 // null term
        tSendByte[offset+2] = 0x00;                                 // null term

        offset = offset + 2;

        if (tType != "") 
        {
            //Type Header
            tSendByte[offset+1] = 0x42;                                 // HI for Type Header 66
            tSendByte[offset+2] = Convert.ToByte(typesizeHi);           // Length of Type Header
            tSendByte[offset+3] = Convert.ToByte(typesizeLo);           // Length of Type Header

            for (i=0;i<=(tTypeLen-1);i++) 
            {
                tSendByte[offset+4+i] = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToChar(tType.Substring(i,1)));
            }
            tSendByte[offset+3+tTypeLen+1] = 0x00;                      // null terminator

            offset = offset+3+tTypeLen+1;
        }

        //Body
        tSendByte[offset+1] = 0x49;                                 //HI End of Body 73
        tSendByte[offset+2] = Convert.ToByte(filesizeHi);           //
        tSendByte[offset+3] = Convert.ToByte(filesizeLo);           //1k payload + 3 for HI header

        for (i=0;i<=(fileLen-1);i++) 
        {
            tSendByte[offset+4+i] = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToChar(tFileContent.Substring(i,1)));
        }
        //tSendByte[offset+4+fileLen] = 0x00;                           // null terminator

        offset = offset+3+fileLen;

        stream.Write(tSendByte,0,tSendByte.Length );

        //listen for server response

        //TODO: can hang here forever waiting response...

        bool x = stream.DataAvailable; // changed bluetoothclient - public NetworkStream GetStream()

        byte[] tArray4 = new byte[3];
        stream.Read(tArray4,0,3);

        x = stream.DataAvailable;

        if (tArray4[0] == 160) // 0xa0
        {
            int plength = (tArray4[1] * 256) + tArray4[2] - 3;
            byte[] tArray5 = new byte[plength];
            if (plength >0) 
            {
                stream.Read(tArray5,0,plength);
                //TODO: data in returned packet to deal with
            }
            return 160;
        }

        if (tArray4[0] == 197) // 0xc5 Method not allowed
        {
            return 197;
        }

        if (tArray4[0] == 192) // 0xc0 Bad Request
        {
            return 192;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

i want to read the phone book of mobile but i not succeeded yet 
i try on one samsung mobile it gives error bad request i follow the solutions above mentioned but when name = null then obexrequest function gives error

when i try it on huawei mobile it gives unknown error

i try this code as well it throw error that this method is not implemented

[Read contacts using obex in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094515/read-contacts-using-obex-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1)

i call these functions like this

```
            string tName = "";
            string tType = "text/x-vCard";
            string tFileContent = "";

            int result = OBEXRequest("GET",tName,tType,tFileContent);

            switch (result)
            {
                case 160: // 0xa0
                    addtolog("OK");
                    break;

                case 197: // 0xc5
                    addtolog("Method not allowed");
                    break;

                case 192: // 0xc0
                    addtolog("Bad Request");
                    break;

                default:
                    addtolog("Other Error");
                    break;
            }
```

can any body point out my mistake